# Confluence API v2 Page viewers list

Tags: confluence

Is there a way to get the list of viewers on a page using the Confluence API v2? I can't seem to find anything relevant https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v2/intro/#about , We want to know how many anonymous users viewed a page. The closet I found was the views and viewers end points (in v1) but that just gives the count....